# How exactly am i supposed to link these libraries?(SDL)

Tags: c, gcc, sdl, c99, dynamic-linking

This is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<SDL2/SDL.h>
#include<SDL2/SDL_image.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_GetError();
    SDL_Quit();

    /*
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO|SDL_INIT_AUDIO)!=0)
    {
        printf("failed to initialize SDL_VIDEO and/or SDL_audio\n");
        SDL_GetError();
        SDL_Quit;
        return 1;
    }*/
    return 0;
}
```

The commented code is just what i have tried before yielding the same error

The command i used:

```
gcc -o test test.c
```

I have also tried linking the library but i didn't understand the man page and where exactly it wanted me to link it to and exactly what i needed to link to either

Comment: The usual [`gcc -o test test.c \`pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2\``](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) not work for some reason?

Comment: I didn't know about this. I'll try it now thank you. Edit: works fine thank you so much

Comment: You want `gcc -o test test.c \`sdl2-config --cflags --libs\``

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation

Comment: @HolyBlackCat SDL2 has its own config `sdl2-config` [not to be confused with `pkg-config`]. On my system, it gives additional cflags not found from [equiv] `pkg-config`.

Comment: @CraigEstey Ah my bad, didn't actually read the comment.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Personally, in the past, I've just used `pkg-config`. But, I got the `sdl2-config` from another answer/comment on SO.

Comment: so i should use ```sdl2-config``` then and again thank you for such a quick response

Comment: @CraigEstey Hmm, I get the same flags. Given that `pkg-config` is universal and `sdl-config` is something that SDL invented, I usually go with the former.